# Pygame - How to make the number of obstacles that need to be dodged increase

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I want to program my game in such a way that as your points progress, the obstacles that are approaching the player are faster and there are more of them at once. I've played around with my code and have done some research, but everything I try seems to fail. Python isn't giving me any errors, it is just that more obstacles are not appearing.

```
enemy = pygame.image.load('tauros1.png')
....
def things(thingx, thingy):
gameDisplay.blit(enemy, (thingx, thingy))
....
thing_starty = -100
thing_speed = 7
thing_width = 42
thing_height = 43
thing_startx = random.randrange(192, displayWidth - 192)

dodged = 0
....
    things(thing_startx, thing_starty)
    thing_starty += thing_speed

    if thing_starty > displayHeight:
        thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
        thing_startx = random.randrange(192, ((displayWidth - 192) - thing_width))
        dodged += 1
        thing_speed += 2
```

These are the components of the code that make up the enemy base. I've tried implementing while loops, for loops, and embedded if statements. I can't think of anything else to try.

Comment: If you keep you're spirits in a list, let's say that the list contained the (x, y) coordinates of each, you could first move each spirit and then blit them, allowing you to have much more control over your game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give you a complete answer with code specific for your game, but I can give you a few tips to make the whole thing simpler, which will in turn give you more control over all the elements in your game.

First off, you should have a "container" for your sprites. You could have one for everything or, better, have them grouped in a way that makes sense. For example you might have environment sprites, enemies, allies, HUD, etc. What determines how you group your sprites is essentially what they do: similar-behaving sprites should be grouped together.
You could use an array, but since you're using `pygame` I'd suggest `pygame.sprite.Goup` - this implements methods like `.update` and `.draw` which will greatly improve the comprehensibility of your code - and therefore your control over the game.

The you should have a "game loop" (though I'm guessing you already do), which is the place where everything happens, at each frame. Something like:

```
# This code is only intended as a generic example. It wouldn't work on it's
# own and has many placehoders, of course. But you can adapt your
# game to have this kind of structure.

# Game clock keeps frame rate steady
theClock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Sprite groups!
allsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
environmentSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemySprites = pygame.game.Group()

# Initially populate sprite groups here, e.g.
environmentSprites.add(rockSprite)
allsprites.add(rockSprite)
# ...

# Game loop
while True:
    theClock.tick(max_fps)

    # Add new enemies:
    spawn_enemies(enemySprites, allSprites, player_score)

    # Update all sprites
    environmentSprites.update()
    enemySprites.update()
    playerSprite.update()

    # ...and draw them
    allSprites.draw(background)
    window.blit(background)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

This way you can keep your game loop short (as in not many lines, externalize most of the actual work to functions and methods) and therefore have more control over what happens.

Achieving what you wanted is now much, much simpler. You have a single function which does that, and only that, which means that you can focus on just how you want the enemies to spawn in relation to the `player_score`. Just an example off the top of my head:

```
def spawn_enemies(enemyGroup, all, player_score):
    # Calculate the number of enemies you want
    num_enemies = player_score / 100
    for i in range(num_enemies):
        # Create a new enemy sprite instance and
        #   set it's initial x and y positions
        enemy = EnemyClass()
        enemy.xpos = random.randint(displayWidth, displayWidth + 100)
        enemy.ypos = random.randint(0, displayHeight)
        enemy.velocity = (player_score / 100) * base_velocity
        # Add the sprite to the groups, so it'll automatically
        # be updated and blitted in the main loop!
        enemyGroup.add(enemy)
        all.add(enemy)
```

I suggest you read up on the [pygame docs and tutorials](http://www.pygame.org/docs/) for things like `pygame.sprite.Sprite`, `pygame.sprite.Group` and `pygame.time.Clock` if you haven't already. I found them really useful when developing my games. The tutorialy also give a pretty good idea of how the game is best structured.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I gave examples using `pygame` sprites and groups, but you can do it any way you like of course, e.g. use lists and (x, y, v) tuples. The principle stays the same. This is just how I like to do it ;)